# Angular material select drop down with multiple option not hiding inside Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material dialog and inside that, there are few mat-select(all of them enabled multiselect). once I select the options and click on the next select previous one stays.

I will share the image of the problem here

[Image that shows the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNuyq.png)

initially, the mat select was behind the dialog and I used the following CSS styling to make
select on top of dialog.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box { z-index: 10000 !important; }
```